# How to execute INSERT prepared statement using sqlite-simple?

Tags: sqlite, haskell, sqlite-simple

[sqlite-simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple) is able to create prepared statements, but I cannot figure out how to use them with instructions that do not return results. That is:

```
main = do
  db <- open "test.db"
  let a = 1
  let b = 2
  withStatement db "INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?)" $ \stmt -> do
    bind stmt (a, b)
    ???
    reset stmt
```

The one API that "fits" in `???` is `nextRow` which requires data to be returned. So, how are prepared statements that return no results supposed to be used?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple-0.4.9.0/docs/Database-SQLite-Simple.html#g:15 has `execute` and variants.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm asking about how to execute *prepared statements*, not regular SQL.

Comment: Author of sqlite-simple here, only now spotted this question.  There is a work-around to use nextRow with a type annotation for "IO Maybe [Int]".

A "void returning" variant of nextRow has been requested in https://github.com/nurpax/sqlite-simple/issues/50.  This looks like something that should be added in one way or another.